# How to get latest amount of sql subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to get the latest amount transaction of each stockist, not the total their transaction.

There two tables stockist

Stockist table

```
stid  memberid stockistname     area_c

1      4         Roger           Sp Park
2      6         John            Little Garden
3      77        Lily            White D
4      32        Meredith        Dare street
```

transactions table

```
trans_id  memberid  trans_type    amount     trans_date

300      4             cp         250        2015-12-01 00:00:56
301      6             cp         100        2015-12-01 01:20:56
302      6             cp         130        2015-12-03 11:03:51
303      77            cp          74        2015-12-03 13:03:51
304      32            cp          25        2015-12-04 11:00:02
305      6             cp         425        2015-12-04 17:00:02
306      4             cp         235        2015-12-05 06:00:02
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM stockist  LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE trans_type='cp' ORDER BY trans_id DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
transactions ON stockist.memberid=transactions.memberid ORDER BY stockist.stockistname ASC
```

The results are :

```
 John $0
 Lily $0
 Meredith $0
 Roger $0
```

I get the list all stockists name but the amount is zero,
it suppose to show

```
John $425
 Lily $74
 Meredith $25
 Roger $235
```

Actually, in my PHP code, my code looks like this but it not fast enough. I wish to make it faster.

```
$x=1;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stockist ORDER BY stockistname ASC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$memberid=$row['memberid'];
$stockistname=$row['stockistname'];

   $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE memberid='$memberid'  AND  trans_type='cp' ORDER BY trans_id LIMIT 1");
   $row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
   $latest_amount=$row2['amount'];

   echo "<p> $x - $stockistname $ $latest_amount </p>";

$x++;
}
```

Solution :

```
select * from
stockist, (select * from transactions where trans_type='cp' ORDER BY trans_id DESC) transactions
where
stockist.memberid=transactions.memberid 
GROUP BY memberid
ORDER BY stockist.stockistname ASC
```

Thanks to you all

Comment: Why are you doing a subquery in your join?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select stockist.stockistname, amount from
stockist, (select memberid,amount,MAX(trans_date)  from transactions where trans_type='cp' GROUP BY memberid) transactions
where
stockist.memberid=transactions.memberid
ORDER BY stockist.stockistname ASC
```

Comment: yes,it did work but the amount is not latest . However thanks to your code, i be able get the answer i looking for. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your limiting causing the problem.. Try using a correlated query to compare the maximum date like this:

```
SELECT * FROM stockist s
LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions t
 ON(t.memberid = s.memberid and t.trans_type = 'cp')
WHERE t.trans_date = (select max(f.trans_date) from transactions f
                      where f.memberid = t.memberid and f.trans_type = 'cp')
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Also you moved the subquery out of the join

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happen ? what returned from this query

Answer (score 0):

Try Order by amount

```
SELECT * FROM stockist   
LEFT JOIN  transactions  ON  stockist.memberid = transactions.memberid 
WHERE trans_type='cp' 
GROUP BY stockistname ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1
```